AttributeError: type object 'Pinecone' has no attribute 'from_existing_index'
I'm developing a medical chatbot that uses Pinecone for vector storage and SentenceTransformer for generating embeddings. The issue in your code arises from attempting to use a deprecated method from_existing_index.
I'm trying to build a medical chatbot that can respond to user queries by leveraging vector embeddings stored in Pinecone. The chatbot aims to understand user questions, like "What are Allergies," and retrieve relevant information by performing similarity searches on an existing index of medical knowledge.

Pinecone.from_existing_index is not a valid function in Pinecone. Previously, from_existing_index was a method in both the Pinecone Indexclass and PineconeVectorStoreclass, used to initialize a vector store.However, these  methods are deprecated in the latest version."

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The from_existing_index has deprecated and you can perform the same by using
 pc = Pinecone(api_key=api_key)
 index = pc.Index(index_name)
 index.describe_index_stats() ## For verification

You can refer to the Pinecone official Notebook
langchain-retrieval-augmentation.ipynb
